# Still Showing lower version after updation and installation of boost

Tags: linux, centos

I installed boost_1_48_0 on my centOS-6 machine but when i installed mapnik then it shows:

Checking for Boost version >= 1.34... no
Boost version 1.34 or greater is requred.

please resolve the issue.

hope to hear from you soon.

Regards,

Parmanand

Comment: Anyhow above problem is resolved but facing new problem c++ boost_system, boost_filesystem, boost_thread dependencies were not found

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the boost directory:

```
./configure PREFIX=/path/to/your/mapnik/install/directory BOOST_INCLUDES=/path/to/your/boost/include/directory BOOST_LIBS=/path/to/your/boost/lib/directory 
make && make
```

For boost installation, I installed all boost lib :

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/path/to/your/boost/include/directory
./bjam 
./bjam install
```

But you can install the libraries you need

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/path/to/your/boost/include/directory -with-libraries=system,filesystem,thread
```

If this does not resolve the problem, please give more logging information.